# Is Jmeter allow to select the option/value from the dropdown list

Tags: performance, jmeter

In My application which I am testing there is a drop down and I have to select the option/value from the list, After selection the value there is a text field which get auto populated. So can we do the same in Jmeter.

Please share the experience if any body has done.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you do mean auto-populated? Value from drop down gets auto-generated or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This will be quite difficult.
Selecting the value from the dropdown list is easy.  But then your application probably makes an AJAX request to the server to populate the other values.  So you would have to :

- set up a separate HTTP Request which simulates your AJAX request
- parse the HTTP response for the variables you need
- save them into jMeter variables
- use those to populate your next page request (the form submit)

A much easier way is to use some test data which you already know, and just submit your form with those fields hardcoded into jMeter.